# submit form with specified commit parameter

Tags: javascript, submit, form-submit

when I submit from my button the post has a parameter "commit"=>"Save Changes" automatically associated with the text of the button

when I submit inside the script

document.choices.submit()

I don't get this parameter, only the form data.  I need to identify the submission source and so need to specify a 'commit' value from the script

How can i add the 'commit' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As the form event is subsequent to button click the event origin will be the form, so IMHO is better to detect click before submission on click event:

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

// Button #1
document.getElementById('submit1').onclick = () => {
    console.log('submit1');
    myForm.submit();
};

// Button #1
document.getElementById('submit2').onclick = () => {
    console.log('submit2');
    myForm.submit();
};
```

```html
<Form id="myForm">
 <input type="text" />
 <button id="submit1">Submit #1</button>
 <button id="submit2">Submit #2</button>
</Form>
```

Comment: I don't want to have multiple buttons - and that does't help anyway as the submit form the script still won't specify the commit parameter - only the form data. I don't want to use an input ...

Comment: I'm adding a confirm dialog - the dialog will submit on confirm - it needs to identify itself uniquely - surely that's possible.

Comment: It depends, if a `click`on different element triggers the confirm it is possible for sure, if the confirm is triggered by form submit is not possible less than you store the click event data somewhere. If you commit a more relevant code it will help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `<button>` instead of `<input type="submit" />` or add method `preventDefault()` for submit button to track your issue and customise button behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so it was pretty simple when I thought about it - I just appended an input with the details I wanted before I submit

$dialogContainer.dialog({
      show: 'show',
      modal: true,
      dialogClass: 'archive-dialog',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          class: 'btn-secondary',
          click: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close')
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Confirm",
          class: 'btn-primary',
          id: 'btn_confirm',
          click: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close')
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
            **$('form[name=choices]').append("")**
            document.choices.submit()
          }
        }]
    }).prev().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide() // Hide the standard close button

Appending the input to the submitting form just gave me the parameter that submit from the button would give.. but with new text

Comment: $('form[name=choices]').append("<input name='commit' value='Commit Choices'>")